# What's the Java EE Payload Extractor Pattern?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, design-patterns

Can anyone give a brief overview of the Java EE 6 "Payload Extractor" pattern?

Oracle seems to be promoting this as a key pattern for Java EE 6 but I don't see any information online about it other than in a single book (which I don't have at the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is defined in the book: [Real World Java EE Pattern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0557078326) based on this [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/book-real-world-java-ee) so your best bet is to purchase that book.

Comment: Yes, it's on my list of books to purchase.  Other than in this book and in Oracle's courseware, I don't see it described anywhere and I may be asked about it tomorrow.

Comment: A tad too late, but you should include here some small exerpt or your own words describing the pattern, because once the links go dead your answer's value drops to zero. "Your princess is in THAT castle" does not make Mario happier than "another".